# Are GNOME APIs stored in *.so files?

Tags: gnome

Like Windows' API are in the kernel.dll,user32.dll,etc., are GNOME API stored in *.so files?

If so, where are they? Can I use them as a shared library in my program?

If not, what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.so are "Shared Objects" as known as dynamic libraries, different from ".a" that are static libraries.
I think in windows system there are only .dll (dynamically linked libraries).

Gnome APIs, since gnome is only a desktop environment, which makes use of other softwares elements like Nautilus (its window manager) etc.  have exectuables and libraries (i suppose mixed betwwen static and dynamic.
Moreover it will use other libraries like libpng or libjpeg for images, libalsa for sound etc. etc.
and GTK (gnome toolkit) for the GUI

Finally more of them probably are in /usr/lib /usr/share/lib /usr/X11/lib ... and similar  paths

Comment: Windows most definitely has static libaries -- `.lib` files. You just rarely see them in the main system directories.

Comment: `Finally more of them probably are in /usr/lib /usr/share/lib /usr/X11/lib ... and similar paths` Where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

GNOME is only a Desktop Environment - it provides you with high functionalities to manage the desktop, on top of the Window Manager, that manages windows on top of X.org, and so on.

There isn't a (single and well defined) set of GNOME APIs: you use various libraries from various projects. In general, GNOME stuff use GTK+ as their graphical libraries, plus lots of other libs, some quite GNOME\GTK-specific, while some others are more general. You can have a look here for info [1]

On your system, you'll find their binaries in .so objects somewhere (e.g in /usr/lib, /usr/share/lib, and so on).

To **use** them in your program, you have to `#include` the corresponding headers, for example `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` to use the GTK libs (the headers aren't installed by default in many distros, for example in Debian and Ubuntu you have to download the `lib{libraryname}-dev` package with apt-get).

To **compile**, you have to tell the linker and the compiler where are the libraries you want to compile against. To do that, you can use `pkg-config` [2] to find the right gcc `-L` and `-I` switches for most libraries (or you can setup your IDE - or instruct your Makefile - to do that)

[1] http://developer.gnome.org/

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config

Comment: There is too a single and well-defined set of GNOME APIs: it says so right there on the front page of developer.gnome.org that you link to! Scroll down to "Platform Overview."

Comment: `On your system, you'll find their binaries in .so objects somewhere (e.g in /usr/lib, /usr/share/lib, and so on).`All my question is where exactly? Which ones?

Comment: @ptomato Indeed. There's a lot of libraries, APIs, and such that together are the GNOME platform. But a lot of those listed in http://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/stable/ are not GNOME-specific, for example D-Bus, GTK+, Webkit, Gstreamer (GStreamer can be used as a Phonon backend in KDE, D_Bus is used also by KDE and is part of freedesktop, ...). And there are APIs very GNOME-specific (GIO, ...).

Comment: @texasbruce Did you search for them in /usr/lib and /usr/share/lib? They should by there... which ones depends upon which library are you looking for... http://developer.gnome.org/gio/ is located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so in my system, and so on..

Comment: @ptomato Maybe you meant things like GIO, keyring and so on by gnome apis? However, sorry for the confusion =)

Comment: @marcello, GIO is most definitely not Gnome-specific. Gnome-keyring may have "Gnome" in the name, but the set of Gnome APIs is the one on the platform overview. All the core Gnome apps are written using those libraries. All of them can also be used outside of Gnome. But we're digressing from the topic here.